# Applying gsub to tweak the syntax of a customized function

Tags: r, function, gsub

I have a (long) customized function and am wondering if there's a way to apply gsub to tweak the syntax for that function.

As an illustration, my original customized function looks like:

```
mymodel <- function(dataname){
  m <- lm(DV ~ IV, data = dataname)
  [a bunch of other lines to plot the results]
}
```

And I'd like to create another customized function like:

```
mymodel2 <- function(dataname){
  m <- lm(DV ~ IV + COVARIATE, data = dataname)
  [same lines as in mymodel syntax to plot the results]
}
```

Ideally I'm thinking of a solution like:

```
mysyntax <- '
  m <- lm(DV ~ IV, data = datname)
  [other lines to plot the results]
'

mysyntax2 <- gsub('DV ~ IV', 'DV ~ IV + COVARIATE', mysyntax) 
# this will keep all the other lines identical to mysyntax, other than the model specification
```

and then inputting this to create my customized function:

```
mymodel <- function(datname){mysyntax}
mymodel2 <- function(datname){mysyntax2}
```

I might be missing something very obvious, but I can't seem to find a way to pass a vector (`mysyntax` or `mysyntax2`) as an argument to a function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Function bodies are not strings. They are language objects. You can't use string functions to manipulate them. If you do want to use strings, then you would need to parse and evaluate those strings to turn them into functions. But normally treating code as strings is something you might do in a macro-like language, not a functional language like R. Typically you'd just create a base function with a parameter than you can easily swap out and then wrap your specific helper functions around that.

Comment: @MrFlick that makes total sense, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest just defining a basic function `mymodel_` with wrappers:

```
mymodel_ <- function(dataname, formula){
  m <- lm(formula, data = dataname)
}

mymodel1 <- function(dataname, formula = DV ~ IV) mymodel_(dataname, formula)
mymodel2 <- function(dataname, formula = DV ~ IV + COVARIATE) mymodel_(dataname, formula)
```

**1a)** or define a factory function that creates other functions

```
mymodelFactory <- function(formula) {
  function(dataname) {
    m <- lm(formula, data = dataname)
  }
}

mymodel1 <- mymodelFactory(DV ~ IV)
mymodel2 <- mymodelFactory(DV ~ IV + COVARIATE)
```

**2)** Although I don't really recommend this you can modify the `mymodel` function shown in the Note at the end like this:

```
mymodel3 <- mymodel 
body(mymodel3)[[2]][[3]][[2]] <- DV ~ IV + COVARIATE
mymodel3
```

**3)** This is not really recommended either but it can also be done using strings

```
s <- sub("DV ~ IV", "DV ~ IV + COVARIATE", format(mymodel))
mymodel4 <- eval(parse(text = s))
mymodel4
```

### Note

```
mymodel <- function(dataname) {
  m <- lm(DV ~ IV, data = dataname)
}
```